# URL response payment from globalpaymnet to Odoo

Tags: odoo, global, payment, odoo-11, realex-payments-api

i am trying to implement a hpp full redirect to realex payment from Odoo, the transaction is successful but it does not redirect to my website neither giving any response. Here is my code:

```
<template id="global_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="data_set" t-att-data-action-url="tx_url" data-remove-me=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" t-att-value="timestamp"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" t-att-value="merchant_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ACCOUNT" t-att-value="account_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="shared_secret" t-att-value="shared_secret"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" t-att-value="order_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" t-att-value="global_amount"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="CAD"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value="Mobile Channel"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="HPP_VERSION" value="2"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CHANNEL" value="ECOM"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="HPP_LANG" value="en"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" t-att-value="SHA1HASH"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="HPP_POST_RESPONSE" value="http://localhost:8069"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL" value="http://localhost:8069/">



        </template>
```

This how it works using Odoo, I ma not getting any response with any of HPP_POST_RESPONSE or MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL. Note that i have full acces to the merchant site in globalpaymnet.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: When you post the above code on their sandbox URL, do you get the HPP window? OR does the URL changes to something like https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/card.html?guid=b3cfa79e-2b60-4f2a-9dad-cfa897f17189

Comment: it changes to the url you posted, wich is the hpp window i think..

Comment: Globalpayments docs says that the response returned to your specified URL is in the form of HTTP POST, so you should get it by print_r($_POST) on your MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL. It should print all the requested fields. let me know if that does not work

Comment: One more thing to clarify here, that URL provided in MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL field does not really act like the way you would expect, it can show responses/errors from Globalpayments and can print that response by printing the POST global varibale on the same page if you want. You can use this page for checking your response parameters either they match or not. After that you can redirect the user to e.g sorry/thank-you pages based on conditions.

Comment: It does not work, because the doc, also, says that this returned_url should be configured by their support team..well, I've got some news, that i'll just stick with the api integration so no hpp. Thanks anyway for your support.

Comment: @Imed How can we change or update the returned_url for the sandbox account. Can you show me that page using the screenshot or URL?

Comment: @BhavinThummar , Hey, i just added the picture, is this what your are looking for ? (look at the url). My problem was when I submit, it should be going back to Odoo ( We 're no more working on this now..just saying)

Comment: @Imed, BTW We have solved our problem. Our problem is related to one PHP error on the success page of  return URL so according to payment getaways which only accept the proper HTML response from our success or return URL. They(server) have called our return URL using the ajax request on them server by the one curl function which call our return URL on them server.

Comment: @BhavinThummar , great job ! so from what you are saying, the returned url should be configured first from global payment team ?

Comment: Yes, Your return url must be whiltelisted by the payment server. And also your return url page is error free means there are no error or warning on your return page. Other wise payment server does not display the response from your return url page.

Comment: @BhavinThummar, thanks for sharing this info with me! :)